# Need help with proof of $\frac{1}{2}n^{3/2} \leq \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Can someone please help me with this proof? I tried approaching it using a proof by induction.

The base case with $n = 0$ is intuitively true. For the inductive step, I let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $P(n) = \frac{1}{2}n^{3/2} \leq \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{n}$, assumed $P(k)$ and tried to prove $P(k+1)$. For the inductive step, I got $\frac{1}{2}k^{3/2} + \sqrt{k+1} \leq \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}$ by adding $\sqrt{k+1}$ to both sides of the inductive hypothesis. Some basic algebra allows us to rewrite the statement: $\frac{1}{2}k \cdot k^{1/2} + \sqrt{k+1} \leq \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}$.

I'm not exactly sure how to move forward from here. I've tried manipulating the statement in various ways, but I can never get back to $P(k+1)$. Can someone please help to solve this proof, and understand the proof behind it? Thank you!!

Comment: Estimate $\int_0^n x^{1/2}\,dx$.

Comment: Thanks for the link Martin!